# Test case for it('should create'

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

When writing test cases for your Angular components should you keep the generated test to check the component is created?

eg

```ts
it(should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
 });
```

Should this always be the first test case before testing the component functions or should I remove this test and only test the functions of the component, ie http calls, button clicks, page title, calculations etc.

Comment: If you go by TDD concept, you need to write test cases earlier than writing code. In such scenario, checking whether the component has been properly initiated, would be the first check. But, yes, its not mandatory but a general practice.

Answer (score 0):

I usually leave them as the first test in my specs but there really is no need to as all of my other tests passing that test actual functionality of the component will make sure the component can create.

Looking through a few specs in open source projects like ngx-bootstrap it seems they remove the default test from the specs.

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/spec/pagination.component.spec.ts